# How to query LinqToTwitter with multiple id's at once?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-twitter

I am using the linqtotwitter function below to get statuses by ID and it works as expected. But I was wondering if there was a way to only call this function once(by passing the collection of id's to the query and the function would return a collection). Because the way I am currently getting statuses by looping through the collection of Id's and call `GetTweetByKey` each time.

C#:

```
public async Task<Status> GetTweetByKey(string key, StatusType statusType)
{
    try
    {
        return await (
        from tweet in _twitterContext.Status
        where tweet.Type == statusType &&
              tweet.ID == Convert.ToUInt64(key) &&
              tweet.TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended &&
              tweet.IncludeEntities == true
        select tweet).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you with the issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There are several ways to do it, the best would probably be using `join`.</strike> <sub>(This seems to get nowhere, because if any ID is not found, an exception is thrown, so that *no* tweet can be returned).</sub>

Try wrapping your original code with:

```
public async Task<List<Status>> GetTweetByKeys(string[] keys, StatusType statusType)
{
    var tasks = keys.Select(key => GetTweetByKey(key, statusType)).ToArray();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results.ToList();
}
public async Task<Status> GetTweetByKey(string key, StatusType statusType)
{
    try
    {
        return await (
        from tweet in _twitterContext.Status
        where tweet.Type == statusType &&
              tweet.ID == Convert.ToUInt64(key) &&
              tweet.TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended &&
              tweet.IncludeEntities == true
        select tweet).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried, and the problem I am trying to fix now is if the Tweet Id does not exist it goes to my catch block. I just want to get Tweet that exit and return it

Comment: What's the exception message? Does it happen also with your original code?

Comment: `{LinqToTwitter.TwitterQueryException: No status found with that ID.
   at LinqToTwitter.Net.TwitterErrorHandler.BuildAndThrowTwitterQueryException(String responseStr, HttpResponseMessage msg)
   at LinqToTwitter.Net.TwitterErrorHandler.HandleGenericErrorAsync(HttpResponseMessage msg)
   at LinqToTwitter.Net.TwitterErrorHandler.ThrowIfErrorAsync(HttpResponseMessage msg)`

Comment: `Yes I was getting the exception in the original code but it was ok because if the tweet does not exist I would create a new instance of my tweet object which represent not found. with the original code if one tweet no longer exist it does not matter because it gets handled on a higher level where has in the answer if one does not exit I get none because I get the exception

Comment: I see. Well, It seems that you'll have to iterate each key and await all calls. I edited my answer to show how to do it.